# HTML5/Javascript - How to get the coordinates of a shape/image on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Say I drew a rectangle on the canvas. Surely there is some sort of built in method to get the XY coordinates, and dimensions of that rectangle? But after some googling I came up with nothing. And just to clarify, I am not talking about the coordinates of the canvas element itself, but rather a shape/image that is drawn unto the canvas.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In that case is there **some** way to get coordinates? Simply telling me that the way I thought it would be done doesn't exist isn't particularly helpful

Comment: When you draw the rectangle you must know the coordinates right? Just save it in a variable or a property.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a 2D canvas drawing, then the drawing maps 1:1 with screen coordinates, so it is just location of `<canvas>` + location of the drawing.

To clarify, drawing on a `<canvas>` basically just changes the pixels of the canvas - after you draw to it, you can't reference the drawn object the same way you can reference an html element.

Comment: So if I had a canvas which coordinates were X:10, Y:10, and a rectangle within that canvas which coordinates were X:20, Y:20. Does that mean that the coordinates of the rectangle would be at X:30, Y:30?

Comment: @TehEpicPineapple yes, exactly

Comment: What I was really asking is, if I want to get a shape coordinates and say, store it in a variable, can that be done? I would be using this for things like games where the coordinates of the player/AI/etc can differ.

Comment: "the drawing maps 1:1 with screen coordinates..." not true in general! True only so long as the HTML values of width/height and the CSS values of width/height are the same. But if they're different, implicit scaling will take place.You may need to un-scale with the ratio of canvas.offsetWidth (or height) to the width="..." (or height="...") you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is 2D table (Array) of numbers (= pixels = colors). When drawing into canvas, you are just editing this table. When you draw into canvas (= change numbers in table), what should be the coordinates of your adjustment?

If you are drawing rectangles only and you can define the coordinates for your rectangle, you must know your coordinates inside a program, because you have just drawn it.

If you want your image to be separated into some "objects" (shapes), you should use SVG.

Comment: I am asking about this in the context of game programming/animation (which I probably should have clarified) so you don't always know where the coordinates of something are.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should be using canvas as a means to output graphics to the screen and the rest of your logic goes straight into the JavaScript that powers your game/application. The best way to go about making something like this is to create objects and assign properties to them; in its simplest form that can look like this:

```
function Player(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var examplePlayerObject = new Player(20, 20);
```

By extending this object via prototyping you can create multiple copies of an object that has the exact same functions; such as draw. Drawing the player in this instance could just be a red square that is 20px*20px.

```
Player.prototype.draw = function()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
}
```

Then, you should have an update step with some means of clearing what is on the screen and redrawing the parts which have changed.

```
function animationStep()
{
    examplePlayerObject.x++;
    examplePlayerObject.y++;
    examplePlayerObject.draw();
}
```

This animation step should run each frame; look into requestAnimationFrame for smooth animation. [Paul Irish has a good shim](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) for older browsers. Add in `requestAnimationFrame(animationStep)` at the end of that function and you will have a red square moving slowly across the screen. Good luck!